# Response from database is not received to php file

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have been trying to build a register and login android app using php and mysql with android studio. It appears that the values are being entered to the databse but it is not giving a response back. Table name is harry and  php file is:

```
<?php
define('DBUSER', 'id650955_gokulm100');
define('DBPASS', 'gokulm100');
define('DBHOST', 'localhost');
define('DBNAME', 'id650955_harry');

$conn = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);

if (!$conn) {
    die('error connecting to database');
}

echo 'you have created case';


if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["phone"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) 
{
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO harry (username, email, phone, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssis", $username, $email, $phone, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = 1; 

    echo json_encode($response);    
}

else{
    echo "not set";
}
?>
```

Comment: Your `echo 'you have created case';` would be part of the output. This would corrupt your json string.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the data is inserted to the database you need to look at your output, it looks like you're sending json text via json_encode and in the same time echo a string "you have created case"

so your output will be a mix of simple characters and some json string. which probably send a parsing error to the callback in the android side of the code.

first you should add a header that indicates the you will be returning json code  at the top of the file
`header("Content-Type: application/json",true);`

then change all your output to be json , any
`echo "str";`
should be
`echo json_encode(array("message"=>"str"));`

then see if you still don't get any message back.